# How to seed ComplexTypes in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

When migrating the database with EF Core, I get this error:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'AssistantDBContext'. The exception 'The seed entity for entity type 'ContractMainType' cannot be added because it has the complex property 'Rate' set. Complex properties are currently not supported in seeding

And it says that seeding complex type values is not supported!

While in EF, complex types are easily seeded - what do I do?

Easily complex type seeded in EF like this :

```
Rate = new CT_Range { Min = 1, Default = 23, Max = 23 }
```

Comment: how did you configured this `ComplexType` ? I had no problem with complex types in EF Core.

Comment: @RezaNoei Are you sure? There's a difference between *complex* types and *owned* types.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DevBlog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-rc1/) in the section current limitations seed values and other features like constructor injection or nullable context type properties will be added in a later release.

- Add seed data support for complex types. ([Issue #31254](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31253))

You could manually change the migration by adding the additional columns and data of the complex type to the call to InsertData.

Comment: Please add this kind of info in comments. This answer will remain here long after the issue has been solved. Strictly, it's not even an answer to the question, because there are possible work-arounds. Also, you link to another issue than #31254, which is the correct issue and the link to the blog isn't really helpful, because it's about RC versions of EF core 8.

Comment: @GertArnold I think, it is a correct answer, because in the current release it is not implemented yet. The reference to the blog is useful as well as not other documentation of the new feature exists yet. Once the feature is implemented, I will change the answer. But you are correct, I found a workaround which I will add to my answer.

Comment: I certainly hope you will change your answer in due time. Unfortunately Stack Overflow has plenty similar answers that never disappear or change. They only cause confusion.

Comment: But this way of manually adding values when there is a lot of information is very difficult and painful. Is there no other solution other than waiting for the update to  new release?

By the way, I have now installed the preview version 9.0.0 but I still get the same error.